# Find strings with pattern that do not start with a specific attribute

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a regular expression to find incorrect uses of resources in my html file. For this specific test I want to return strings where the string matches `@@[a-zA-Z0-9\._\-]*` but does not start with `i18n="`. This is what I have so far

```
/(?!i18n=")@{2}[a-zA-Z0-9\._\-]+/gi
```

I can't seem to get the negation to work though. These are my test strings but my expression finds a match on the first line which is not what I am expecting.

```
This one is correct and should not be returned i18n="@@DashboardResources.ProgramContentTitle"
Bad, should be returned @@DashboardResources.ProgramContentTitle
@@DashboardResources.ProgramContentTitle is Bad and should be returned.
Bad, should be returned @@DashboardResources.ProgramContentTitle"
Bad, should be returned i8@@DashboardResources.ProgramContentTitle
```

I am using [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Siqdng/1) to test. Any pointers would be most appreciated.

---

*Should it matter, the end use will be in a c# application using the `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex` class.*

Comment: You need a lookbehind, `(?<!i18n=")@{2}[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - Thank you! Do you want to put in an answer? I will accept it as soon as the grace period expires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you want to test a .NET regex, do that at [RegexStorm.net](http://regexstorm.net/tester) or [RegexHero.net](http://regexhero.net/tester) since regex101 does not support the .NET regex syntax. Certainly, regex101 is great as it explains the pattern automatically, but Ultrapico Expresso tool will do the same for you.

Next, the `(?!i18n=")` construct is a look*ahead* and it matches a position that is not immediately followed by `i18n="` substring. What you need is a negative look*behind*, `(?<!i18n=")`, that will match a location that is not immediately *preceded* with a `i18n="` substring.

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(s, @"(?<!i18n="")@@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+")
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(m => m.Value)
        .ToList();
```

If you share more details on what the document looks like and what the requirements are, there might be a different, better soltution here. For a more solid approach to analyze HTML, you may use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex) and similar libraries.

Comment: Thank you again. I created a unit test to iterate over  a folder where we create `.html` files and want to fail the unit test if any html file contains localization resources that do not match the pattern. With your help I have everything but that last piece.

Comment: @Igor: Sorry, I do not get it: do you want an expression that matches `@@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+` pattern after `i18n="`? `@"i18n=""@@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+"`?

Comment: I got it. I added the addition on to what you had but RegEx101 did not like it but the site you recommended (RegexStorm) did. Thank you for that, I will add that link to my favorites.

Comment: I rolled my question back to the original, that is what you provided an answer for so that is most fitting. Thank you again for your fast response and detailed answer!

Comment: @Igor I see, you updated the question while I was writing. Yes, C# regex allows infinite width lookbehind patterns, and you cannot test those at regex101 as it does not support .NET regex syntax.